# Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to save voice features in content provider but then this error occured

```
    02-01 16:47:20.201: D/AndroidRuntime(11623): Shutting down VM
02-01 16:47:20.201: W/dalvikvm(11623): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41831da0)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623): Process: com.neu.val.activity, PID: 11623
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3990)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4658)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19461)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3985)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    ... 11 more
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at android.content.ContentUris.parseId(ContentUris.java:85)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at com.neu.val.activity.CreateVoiceSample.insertFeature(CreateVoiceSample.java:181)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    at com.neu.val.activity.CreateVoiceSample.actionBt(CreateVoiceSample.java:77)
02-01 16:47:20.211: E/AndroidRuntime(11623):    ... 14 more
```

The error occured in line 181 which is this line

```
if (ContentUris.parseId(insert) != -1)
```

I've noticed that the variable "insert" is null but the values that I've tried to the provider were not null.. I guess the 'insert' variable is the main eroor here but I don't know how to solve it . Please help ...

This is the class where the error occured:

CreateVoiceSample.java

```
public class CreateVoiceSample extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button btSpeak, btCancel, btStop, btSave;
    private WaveRecorder waveRecorder;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView timerText;
    private boolean stopped;
    private int MAX_DURATION = 5000, progressTime, seconds;
    private Timer timer;
    static final String TAG = "VAP";
    public String codebookString;
    private long userId;

    /** The recording output file. */
    private static File outputFile = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),
            "recording.wav");

    /**
     * This is actually used to stop the record after the recording time is up
     * as well.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recordvoice);
        userId = getIntent().getLongExtra(Extras.EXTRA_USER_ID, -1);
        initializeVar();
        enableButtons(true, false, false, true);
    }

    public void initializeVar() {
        btSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSpeak);
        btSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
        btStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);
        btCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        stopped = true;
        progressBar.setMax(MAX_DURATION);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        startProgress();

    }

    public void actionBt(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.bSpeak) {
            startRecord();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.bStop) {
            stopRecord();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.bCancel) {
            finish();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.bSave) {
            insertFeature(codebookString);
        }
    }

    private void startRecord() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        enableButtons(false, true, false, false);
        seconds = 1000;
        progressTime = 0;
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        timerText.setText("00:00:00");

        if (outputFile.exists())
            outputFile.delete();
        waveRecorder = new WaveRecorder(8000);
        waveRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        stopped = false;
        try {
            waveRecorder.prepare();
            waveRecorder.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started ... ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecord() {
        stopped = true;
        waveRecorder.stop();
        waveRecorder.release();
        waveRecorder.reset();
        timer.cancel();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording stopped..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        calculateMfccs();
        startProgress();
    }
    public void startProgress() { 
        enableButtons(true,false,true,true);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            progress();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1, 1000);
    }

    public void enableButtons(boolean startBt, boolean stopBt, boolean saveBt,
            boolean cancelBt) {
        btSpeak.setEnabled(startBt);
        btStop.setEnabled(stopBt);
        btSave.setEnabled(saveBt);
        btCancel.setEnabled(cancelBt);
    }

    public void progress() {
        if (!stopped) // call ui only when the progress is not stopped
        {
            if (progressTime < MAX_DURATION) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            int secondsText = seconds / 1000;
                            progressTime = progressBar.getProgress() + 1000;
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressTime);
                            timerText.setText("00:00:0" + secondsText);
                            seconds += 1000;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                stopRecord();
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculateMfccs() {
        new MfccTask(this).execute(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    private void insertFeature(String password) {

        long modeId = ((VoiceApplication)getApplication()).getModeId();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Feature.SUBJECT_ID, 1);
        cv.put(Feature.MODE_ID, 1);
        cv.put(Feature.REPRESENTATION, password);
        Log.i(TAG, ""+userId+""+modeId+""+password);
        Uri insert = getContentResolver().insert(Feature.CONTENT_URI, cv);
        Log.i(TAG, "Inserted voice features to URI: " + insert);

        if (ContentUris.parseId(insert) != -1) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not save features!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    class MfccTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private final Activity parentActivity;

        public MfccTask(Activity parentActivity) {
            this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String filename = params[0];
            WavReader wavReader = new WavReader(filename);

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting to read from file " + filename);
            double[] samples = readSamples(wavReader);

            Log.i(TAG, "Starting to calculate MFCC");
            double[][] mfcc = calculateMfcc(samples);

            FeatureVector pl = createFeatureVector(mfcc);

            KMeans kmeans = doClustering(pl);

            Codebook cb = createCodebook(kmeans);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String codebookJsonString = gson.toJson(cb, Codebook.class);

            return codebookJsonString;
        }

        private Codebook createCodebook(KMeans kmeans) {
            int numberClusters = kmeans.getNumberClusters();
            Matrix[] centers = new Matrix[numberClusters];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberClusters; i++) {
                centers[i] = kmeans.getCluster(i).getCenter();
            }
            Codebook cb = new Codebook();
            cb.setLength(numberClusters);
            cb.setCentroids(centers);
            return cb;
        }

        private KMeans doClustering(FeatureVector pl) {
            long start;
            KMeans kmeans = new KMeans(Constants.CLUSTER_COUNT, pl,
                    Constants.CLUSTER_MAX_ITERATIONS);
            Log.i(TAG, "Prepared k means clustering");
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            kmeans.run();
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Clustering finished, total time = "
                            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
            return kmeans;
        }

        private FeatureVector createFeatureVector(double[][] mfcc) {
            int vectorSize = mfcc[0].length;
            int vectorCount = mfcc.length;
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating pointlist with dimension=" + vectorSize
                    + ", count=" + vectorCount);
            FeatureVector pl = new FeatureVector(vectorSize, vectorCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < vectorCount; i++) {
                pl.add(mfcc[i]);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Added all MFCC vectors to pointlist");
            return pl;
        }

        private short createSample(byte[] buffer) {
            short sample = 0;
            // hardcoded two bytes here
            short b1 = buffer[0];
            short b2 = buffer[1];
            b2 <<= 8;
            sample = (short) (b1 | b2);
            return sample;
        }

        private double[][] calculateMfcc(double[] samples) {
            MFCC mfccCalculator = new MFCC(Constants.SAMPLERATE,
                    Constants.WINDOWSIZE, Constants.COEFFICIENTS, false,
                    Constants.MINFREQ + 1, Constants.MAXFREQ, Constants.FILTERS);

            int hopSize = Constants.WINDOWSIZE / 2;
            int mfccCount = (samples.length / hopSize) - 1;
            double[][] mfcc = new double[mfccCount][Constants.COEFFICIENTS];
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0, pos = 0; pos < samples.length - hopSize; i++, pos += hopSize) {
                mfcc[i] = mfccCalculator.processWindow(samples, pos);
                if (i % 20 == 0) {
                    publishProgress("Calculating features...", i, mfccCount);
                }
            }
            publishProgress("Calculating features...", mfccCount, mfccCount);

            Log.i(TAG, "Calculated " + mfcc.length + " vectors of MFCCs in "
                    + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
            return mfcc;
        }

        private double[] readSamples(WavReader wavReader) {
            int sampleSize = wavReader.getFrameSize();
            int sampleCount = wavReader.getPayloadLength() / sampleSize;
            int windowCount = (int) Math.floor(sampleCount
                    / Constants.WINDOWSIZE);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[sampleSize];
            double[] samples = new double[windowCount * Constants.WINDOWSIZE];

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
                    wavReader.read(buffer, 0, sampleSize);
                    samples[i] = createSample(buffer);

                    if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                        publishProgress("Reading samples...", i, samples.length);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception in reading samples", e);
            }
            return samples;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            codebookString = result; 
            progressDialog.dismiss();   
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(parentActivity);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Working...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Working...");
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);
            progressDialog.setMax(10000);
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            String msg = (String) values[0];
            Integer current = (Integer) values[1];
            Integer max = (Integer) values[2];

            progressDialog.setMessage(msg);
            progressDialog.setProgress(current);
            progressDialog.setMax(max);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neu.val.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:name=".VoiceApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateVoiceSample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.hgb.feature" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="com.neu.val.activity.CREATEVOICESAMPLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VoiceAuthenticator"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.neu.val.intent.AUTH_METHOD" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.neu.val.intent.DO_AUTH.voicerecognition"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.neu.val.service.LockService" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.neu.val.service.BootStartUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.neu.val.database.AuthDb"
            android:authorities="com.neu.val.database">
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: then how will I fix it @Simon

Comment: By reading the answers in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to set a breakpoint in your doInBackground method at CedeBook cb = createCodebook(kmeans):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  :
  :
  Codebook cb = createCodebook(kmeans);
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String codebookJsonString = gson.toJson(cb, Codebook.class);
  return codebookJsonString;
}
```

It seems, that codebookJsonString is null, so this null-value gets returned in your method, and appears as result in the Method onPostexecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
  codebookString = result; 
  progressDialog.dismiss();   
}
```

So your activity member codebookString is null. So when it get accessed on
on insertFeature(codeBookString) null will be used. So the java.lang.NullPointerException will occur.

Two further points:

1. you declared your Method insertFeature(String password).but you are passing the codeBookString, hope this is wanted.
2. The second thing is, that you are logging your password as information, make sure you remove this, when you deploy your app.

   Log.i(TAG, ""+userId+""+modeId+""+password);

Also Make Sure that `Feature.CONTENT_URI` has a valid value.

Comment: Hi @Luke , actually the codebookString and the codebookJsonString both have a value . i print it in the logcat.. so I was wondering why the insert  variable is null ..